# Protecting games from memory scanners (like Cheat Engine)

Tags: c++, security, memory

I'm making a C++11 game where scores are sent to the server. I'm storing the score as a simple float, so people using software like [Cheat Engine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cheat_Engine) could easily change the value of the score before it is sent to server.

How can I protect my game against this kind of attacks?

Comment: You can't. You need to validate data being sent to the server, server-side.

Comment: Send a salted hash at the same time...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are many options you can do but the best is to not accept any important values from the client. Have the server do all the calculation and than send the values to the client.

Comment: This is not always an option.

Comment: @supertonsky How so? I can't think of a single game that doesn't do this.

Comment: There are some games that do its computation on the client but no matter what I do with the game using a cheat engine, I can't simply hack the game. For some reason I couldn't access the memory. Now that's something. Whatever that is, it is brilliant. There are some games you can access the memory but once you get the address, the "variable" seems to keep on changing memory address which essentially renders apps like cheat engine useless.

Comment: The issue is not reading/editing the memory but sending the wrong information to the server. There is nothing that can stop me from sending a message to the server saying I just made a million coins. If this info was not processed server side, than it has no choice but to trust me and edit the database.

Comment: You have a point, but how's that going to work for action games developed for mobile phones if all calculations are done on the server, slight instability on internet connection will surely ruin the gaming experience.

Comment: @supertonsky There are a lot of methods. One way is Dead reckoning http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_reckoning

Comment: You don't need wait the server to respond, you can calculate it at the client side and asynchronously confirm that with the server.

Answer (score 3):

Encrypt any data you care about (or all data if possible) if you have to do anything on the client side in the first place.

Chances are it'll be better to have the server calculate anything important.  For example, in Call of Duty, you want the server to decide who gets shot so that individual players' computers/latency/etc. doesn't get involved.

If you're doing a local-PC only game and just want to upload scores at the end, server calculations aren't an option.  In that case you really have to just stick with encryption and obfuscating the important values in the first place.  There's only so much you can do; it's probably never going to be bullet-proof if it's 100% client side calculated.

Comment: And I expect you could do that without having an encryption key on the client? ;)

Comment: A sophisticated user could extract the encryption key and use it to encrypt whatever score they wish to send to the server

Answer (score 3):

There is really no way that you can ENSURE that the value isn't tampered with. What you could do is send sufficient information to the server that it can determine "is this possible" - for example, if your game is a "Pac-Man" style game, you could also provide all of the "Blobs" that Pac-Man ate, or the number per level and the time it took to complete each level, etc. It's not IMPOSSIBLE that a cheater can reproduce all the extra data needed, but it makes it much harder to do so if you are sending more data across.

But any data that is available at any time in your software is subject to being modified by a "debugger" type application. There's nothing you can do about that.

Answer (score 3):

There will always be a way to bypass your protection. No matter how good it is. However, you can **make it harder**. There is an example: https://github.com/fairylovell/anti-wpm.

Basically, the point is to create two variables with the same value and to move one of them through different positions in the RAM (simply said) to make finding it much harder. Then, compare values for differences.

This is a simplified code for the idea.

```
int VariableToProtect = 0;
int pVar[ 1000 ] = { 0 };
int Pos = 0; // 'pseudo-position' of the element (with same value as VariableToProtect) in pVar

while( !GetAsyncKeyState( VK_SPACE ) )
{
    if( pVar[ Pos ] != VariableToProtect )
        printf( "detected!" );

    ++VariableToProtect;

    Pos = rand( ) % 1000;
    pVar[ Pos ] = VariableToProtect;

    Sleep( 10 );
}
```

Comment: To improve your answer, it would be great if you could add some minimal additional information directly on the answer body, because links can become stale. For example, just explaining in a few sentences what `anti-wpm` is and very roughly how it works.

Comment: Great work @uzivanky! Right now it's actually a much better answer! I'm sure everyone will appreciate the effort.

Answer (score 1):

If it's massively multiplayer, then in theory, you can have some algorithm where the server requests answers to specific questions from a random group of users.  A cheater will get different answers without some major collusion.

If in a game like Call of Duty, you could have 30 players and need a super majority to agree if a kill happened.  That way, no single team could cheat by collusion methods.  You'd still have to watch out for alternate accounts being used to climb a leader board.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use bare variable.

```
int hitpoints; // hackable
```

Use encrypted wrappers.

```
struct SaltedHitpoints
{
     char encrypted[256];
     int getHitpoint()
     {
         return decode(encrypted);
     }
};
```

Do not assign it to any variable. Just pass it to another function so compiler keeps it in register.

No-one reads your **registers**.

```
// pass by value, dx register
// or xmm0 register
consume(enc.getHitpoints());
```

You are not sure if its a register? Then use assembly and keep it in register explicitly. No matter how hard hackers try, a memory scan can not scan anything that is out of memory.